# How to view a full number of followers count from a new version of Facebook page

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to get a full number of followers counts from a new version of Facebook page.
As you can seen, the below picture of a new version has only a shorten number of follower.

[image]

I also try to inspect through the console or search it from network resources but nothing found.

It doesn't like the old version of Facebook page shows the full number like below,
[image]

I really need to get a number of followers count. I need to do this way because the facebook API not allows to do this (only for an owners page).

Or can I use the Facebook Graph API to do this ?. Previously, I tried it and found that it does not allow to do this. I can only get a number of followers count on my own page. Is it correct ?

Comment: Facebook doesn't allow you to scrape them. And yes in GraphAPI you can't get it from random pages.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to get this from `/{page-id}?fields=followers_count`

I believe you would need 'Page Public Metadata Access' feature to get this metric for Pages your app is not installed on.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/feature#page-public-metadata-access
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/features-reference/page-public-metadata-access